# Equality in distribution sense, implies equality almost everywhere

Tags: lebesgue-integral, distribution-theory

Let $\Omega \in \mathbb{R^n}$, (open set). and $f\in L^2(\Omega)$.

If we had the equality in distribution sense : $u=f$  : $(1)$

Does it implies that $u\in L^2(\Omega)$ ?

This is what I did :

Let $\phi \in D(\Omega)$ (test function), from $(1)$ we have

$\int_{\Omega}u.\phi .d\lambda=\int_{\Omega}f.\phi .d\lambda$

$\int_{\Omega}(u-f).\phi .d\lambda=0$ ;$\forall \phi \in D(\Omega)$

Then $u=f \quad$a.e. then $u\in L^2(\Omega)$

Comment: A distribution  is  a function defined on $C_c(\mathbb R^{n})$. Since it is  not function on $\mathbb R^{n}$ it does not make sense to ask if $u=f$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Yeah i agree, but we can identify $L^2$ with a subspace of the distribution space which is the topological dual of $D(\Omega)$

Comment: With that interpretation you have two functions  defined on $C_c(\mathbb R^{n})$ and you are asking if they are equal almost everywhere. What is the reference measure on $C_c(\mathbb R^{n})$?

Comment: Lebesgue measure, by the way this is just an idea of proof (because i read that in a book without proof and I tried and i just want to check if my method is logic)

Comment: You are confused. There is no such thing as Lebesgue measure on $C_c(\mathbb R^{n})$.